# Using different controllers folder in Yii2

Tags: nginx, yii2

I have a domain with different API's. I need to be able to call something like this

http://www.mydomain.xx/api1/v1/controller/action

http://www.mydomain.xx/api2/v1/controller/action

I am using nginx, I am mapping the root to /var/www/myapp/web and I have the API's folders along with backend an frontend folders, parallel to the web folder.

How can I access them without creating differently mapped sub-domanis?

Comment: The yii routes can also contain the full url instead of just controller/action.

Answer (score 0):

To write it as a solution: You might use the [full URL in the route](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/runtime-routing.md#rules-with-server-names-).

```
[
   'http://www.mydomain.xx/api1/v1/<controller>/<action>' => 'api1module/<controller>/<action>',
   'http://www.mydomain.xx/api2/v1/<controller>/<action>' => 'api2module/<controller>/<action>',
]
```

This is assuming you define a contained API as a separate module.

**Per your comment:**
If you are using different domains it might be handy to set a variable in your config file and use that:

```
$domain = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : 'http://www.mydomain.xx/';
```

Then you can extract more variables as well perhaps:

```
[
   "$domain/<api:(api1|api2)>/<version>/<controller>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>',
]
```

In your controller you could fetch the api type and version:

```
public function actionApiAction($api, $version) 
{
    // ...
}
```

Possibilities enough, depends on what you want.

Comment: [ 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/api1/<version>/<controller>/<action>' => '<version>/<controller>/<action>',]  I changed it to this, but I can't figure out how to add this config array to the rules array, it seems it wants some kind of key like 'controller' or 'suffix', could you provide a  configuration of the rules array that includes this?

Comment: You can't have 3 parts in your value unless it is a module name, so `<version>/<controller>/<action>` is not a valid route. Just use `<controller>/<action>`. `<version>` (if you need it) will be available in the `$_GET`, via `\Yii::$app->request->get('version')` or as a parameter to your action function

Comment: 'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                [

                    [
                        'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/api/v1/<controller>/<action>' => 'api/v1/<controller>/<action>'
                    ]
                ]
            ]] this is how it looks an it does not work, as it seems I need to add a key to the array

Comment: Once more: The route part (after the =>) is either `"<module>/<controller>/<action>"` or `"<controller>/<action>"`. Please look at my example. The value should always be a valid internal route.